Movie with the use of a high powered gun
I am looking for the name of a movie :What I recall from the movie from about the 80’s/90’s. Several shooting scenes from a high powered riffle similar to the movie ‘Shooter’ that is once the trigger is pulled you hear the bang then several seconds later you see the mark fall.  The plot is something like the shooter does a job for someone (like the CIA) and they no longer need him and try to dispose of him or some other form of double cross. I remember the final scene after some form of car crash the shooter gets out of the car gets his gun and ramsets (explosive bolt) his gun tripod to the roof of the car and shoots the fleeing vehicle which is going in and out of dips naturally he times it right for the third of fourth dip being several seconds of flight time. I did think the main actor was Wesley Snipes but can’t find it. I also believe the opening scene is a ramset being shot into cement to hold a tripod for a distance shot.


Were you thinking of "Sabotage (1996)"?

An ex-Navy commando is framed for a bungled mission to save hostages
  from terrorists. He survived after being shot 7 times by an
  assassin. 
Years later, he is hired to protect a weapons distributor and his
  wife, only to have the same assassin kill them. 
This sets him on a mission, along with an FBI agent, to bring the
  killers and conspirators to justice.


Mark Dacascos (far right) plays the "nice guy" sniper...

and Tony Todd plays the evil one.

Here's a montage featuring the first scene (just skip to the end) i.e. shooting at a moving vehicle. And here's a clip of the rooftop assassination.

If you want to get a better idea, there's a German dub available here. You'll probably encounter a single pop-up, which can be closed easily enough! Slide the marker to 08:10 to catch the rooftop sequence. Then skip further down to around 1:29:00 for the final shot.
You can read a review here. And for a literal shot-by-shot account of the kills, go here.
~ Movie stills from cinema.de; VHS cover art from Amazon 

Brillant that is the one. Thanks very much Rumandwrite.
